# MySQL get data from Custom table via _prepareCollection

Tags: php, adminhtml, mysql

I'm using Magento 1.9.0.1 and i'm working on custom extension.

I want to get data from custom table and display it in a grid table in page created by me in the admin panel.

Here is the `Grid.php` file for fetching data for the orders:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Status_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('smsnotification_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('increment_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('smsnotification/smsnotification_collection')
            ->join(array('a' => 'sales/order_address'), 'main_table.entity_id = a.parent_id AND a.address_type != \'billing\'', array(
                'city'       => 'city',
                'country_id' => 'country_id'
            ))
            ->join(array('c' => 'customer/customer_group'), 'main_table.customer_group_id = c.customer_group_id', array(
                'customer_group_code' => 'customer_group_code'
            ))
            ->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
                'fullname',
                'CONCAT({{customer_firstname}}, \' \', {{customer_lastname}})',
                array('customer_firstname' => 'main_table.customer_firstname', 'customer_lastname' => 'main_table.customer_lastname'))
            ->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
                'products',
                '(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(\' \', x.name)
                    FROM sales_flat_order_item x
                    WHERE {{entity_id}} = x.order_id
                        AND x.product_type != \'configurable\')',
                array('entity_id' => 'main_table.entity_id')
            )
        ;

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        parent::_prepareCollection();
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $helper = Mage::helper('smsnotification');
        $currency = (string) Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE);

        $this->addColumn('increment_id', array(
            'header' => $helper->__('Order #'),
            'index'  => 'increment_id'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('purchased_on', array(
            'header' => $helper->__('Purchased On'),
            'type'   => 'datetime',
            'index'  => 'created_at'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('products', array(
            'header'       => $helper->__('Products Purchased'),
            'index'        => 'products',
            'filter_index' => '(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(\' \', x.name) FROM sales_flat_order_item x WHERE main_table.entity_id = x.order_id AND x.product_type != \'configurable\')'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('fullname', array(
            'header'       => $helper->__('Name'),
            'index'        => 'fullname',
            'filter_index' => 'CONCAT(customer_firstname, \' \', customer_lastname)'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('city', array(
            'header' => $helper->__('City'),
            'index'  => 'city'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('country', array(
            'header'   => $helper->__('Country'),
            'index'    => 'country_id',
            'renderer' => 'adminhtml/widget_grid_column_renderer_country'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('customer_group', array(
            'header' => $helper->__('Customer Group'),
            'index'  => 'customer_group_code'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
            'header'        => $helper->__('Grand Total'),
            'index'         => 'grand_total',
            'type'          => 'currency',
            'currency_code' => $currency
        ));

        $this->addColumn('shipping_method', array(
            'header' => $helper->__('Shipping Method'),
            'index'  => 'shipping_description'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('order_status', array(
            'header'  => $helper->__('Status'),
            'index'   => 'status',
            'type'    => 'options',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
        ));

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportInchooCsv', $helper->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportInchooExcel', $helper->__('Excel XML'));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }
}
```

Here is the structure of the `VivasIndustries_SmsNotification` table.
I want to display the data only from this table.

[image]

Please tell me how the `Grid.php` file must look like so it will get the information from my custom table `VivasIndustries_SmsNotification`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are lot of tutorials out there. Check http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/ and https://markshust.com/2012/07/05/creating-magento-adminhtml-grids-simplified

Comment: This is not helping me because it is not getting data from custom table. Also i've done everything so far by this guide..

Comment: what is relation between VivasIndustries_SmsNotification and other table

Comment: Tony Stark,i have see   your table is  not containing... entity_id ..

Comment: Does your custom model have a Model set? E.g. can you call `Mage::getModel('VivasIndustries_SmsNotification');` once I know this I will help you modify Grid.php. Also if all you want in the grid is that tables content why are you loading another collection in the `_prepareCollection` method ? Prepare collection is what gets passed to the grid to processor to render the data.

Answer (score 2):

> "I want to display the data only from this table."

All you need to do is map *only* the custom table fields in `_prepareColumns()`. That's it.